# Instant Verification prevents onCodeSent() to ever be called & debugged - Firebase SMS Authentication for Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, sms-verification

In [Firebase SMS Authentication for Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth), I'm trying to debug the stage in which the user has to type in the Verification Code he received via SMS.

However, due to the *Instant Verification*, I cannot recreate this scenario on my phone anymore because the `onCodeSent()` event is never called again. The `onVerificationCompleted()` is called instead - which is GOOD for production, but it leaves me no option to debug my SMS Code Verification screen.

Unfortunately, at the moment [there is no way to disable Instant Verification](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/296) (waiting for @samtstern's response)...

**How can I recreate that scenario again?** at least for debugging?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688761/how-to-resend-sms-verification-in-firebase-phone-authentication-android) didn't help because we can't get the `ForceResendingToken` without triggering the `onCodeSent(..)`, and as I said, I can't get it triggered...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closing this question since @samtstern [has responded to me on Github](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/296#issuecomment-313720246), providing an alternate workaround due to the (current) lack of feature to disable *Instant Verification*:

> That's a good point. I'll make sure to add that to the feature request
>   internally. One workaround is to use two devices. On one device (with
>   no SIM) enter the phone number of the other device (with a SIM). Then
>   you'll get the code flow.

Answer (score -1):

Disabling and re-enabling the sim from settings will skip Instant verification until the next successful OTP verification.

Comment: Please provide more details, how does this answer the question? Please read the SO guidelines before posting.