# How to disable Firebase Phone Auth Android auto-sign-in (onVerificationCompleted callback)

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

Is there a way to disable Android "instant verification" (automatically signing in) with Firebase Phone Auth? There is a way to disable "auto-retrieval" by setting the timeout of verifyPhoneNumber to 0 (Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/auth/PhoneAuthProvider.html). However I cannot find a documented way to disable instant verification.

I am asking because of a potential security issue: removing the SIM card from a device still auto-signs in that user! In other words, a user using another person's old device could be able to sign in using their old phone number. Here are the reproduction steps:

- Be on Android, on a device with a functional SIM card
- Sign in using the number associated with that SIM card
- This triggers auto-sign-in
- Sign out
- Turn device off and remove SIM card
- Turn device back on and attempt signing in with that same number

Observed behavior:
The user is auto-signed in, despite not having the appropriate SIM card

Expected behavior:
If the user's device does not have a SIM card that is associated with the entered phone number, they are not auto-signed-in and an SMS text message is sent to that number.

Comment: Sign out from your Google account from the device with the removed SMS text message and then try again.

Comment: Signing out did not work. I had to wipe the the device with a factory reset to make it work. (Tested on Samsung Galaxy Grand Prime)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Update, 11.5.09 should have reached almost all users' devices. Instant validation will be stopped after a SIM card change. And you can also use this trick for manual testing purpose.

---

In an upcoming Google Play services v11.5 release scheduled for late Q3, SIM card change will be auto-detected which will stop instant validation from working. The new release will be auto-pushed to users' devices and no SDK change is required.

To get the best UX and opt-in rate, it's better to wait for the Play services update rather than adding the scary runtime permission yourself (to read and compare phone number). Thanks for your patience!

Comment: How i can to test my code with manually code verification? onVerificationCompleted is always called

Comment: @pavelPoley You can use a phone number not on the current device

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately it seems that [there isn't a way to disable Instant Verification](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/296#issuecomment-313421431) **at the moment**.

After asking the devs to add this feature (actually for a [different reason](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44974802/instant-verification-prevents-oncodesent-to-ever-be-called-debugged-fireba/44989557#44989557)), I was replied that [it will be added to the feature request](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-android/issues/296#issuecomment-313720246).

Perhaps you should add a comment there too, specifying your security findings. 
Maybe it will speed up the process of adding this feature :)

Answer (score 2):

Not sure when this feature was added, but you can actually add a fake phone number and expected verification code which will override the auto verification:
[image]

Comment: This is different, this is used for testing devices, but the original issue reported on this post affects the real prod users by the auto-verification. You want the real prod users to authenticate via msg code into your app and seems like know you need a listener for the auto-verification

Answer (score 0):

you can get the used phone number at the device by this :

```
TelephonyManager tMgr = (TelephonyManager)mAppContext.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE);
String mPhoneNumber = tMgr.getLine1Number();
```

and add required Permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"/>
```

get the phone number from `FirebaseAuth` like this :

```
String number = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getPhoneNumber();
```

compare between them if it's ok carry on else send the SMS using `twilio` or some services like that

Comment: What would you put in that Twilio SMS? Firebase Phone Auth controls the verification codes. Do you mean have two authentication mechanisms? That sounds like a huge pain. The reason we went with Firebase Phone Auth was so that we didn't have to write our own custom Auth.

Answer (score -1):

No need to change SIM Card!!!!

In order to get OTP/Code multiple time for testing just follow this code
in oncreate of your activity you will get code 
now uninstall the app and verify again you will get a new code it will not instant validate.

if you still not able to do that i will share my full activity code!!

```
 PhoneAuthProvider.getInstance().verifyPhoneNumber(
            phoneNumber,        // Phone number to verify
            60,                 // Timeout duration
            TimeUnit.SECONDS,   // Unit of timeout
            this,               // Activity (for callback binding)
            mCallbacks);        // OnVerificationStateChangedCallbacks
    // [END start_phone_auth]

    mVerificationInProgress = true;
```

Comment: can you explain in detail, how this serve the purpose to disable instant validation ?