# Firebase phone authentication without waiting for verification code

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication, verification

I am working on an app in react native that has phone authentication for user registration. I use firebase for this purpose. The problem is when the user enters the phone number and hits the "send code" button, firebase(Google) successfully sends a verification code to the user via SMS, but before the user enters the confirmation code and hits the "confirm" button, login process starts automatically!!! why this happened? and how can I fix this?

Note:

- This situation won't happen if test phone numbers(provided by firebase) being used.
- The app have no permission to read user SMS content.
- I add SHA-1 and SHA-256 fingerprint for both debug and release in firebase app setting

Authentication logic in my app:

```js
async function onSignUp() {
  setLoading_signUp(true);

  if (phonenumber.length === 10 && name !== '') {
    try {
      const confirmation = await auth().signInWithPhoneNumber(
        '+98' + phonenumber
      );
      setConfirm(confirmation);
      // console.log('confirm ===>   ',confirm);
    } catch (error) {
      setLoading_signUp(false);
      alert(error.message);
    }
  } else if (phonenumber.length !== 10 && name === '') {
    setLoading_signUp(false);
    alert('Invalid Phone number !\nName field should not be empty!');
  } else if (phonenumber.length === 0) {
    setLoading_signUp(false);
    alert('Enter Phone number !');
  } else if (0 < phonenumber.length < 10) {
    setLoading_signUp(false);
    alert('Invalid Phone number !');
  } else {
    setLoading_signUp(false);
    alert('Name field should not be empty!');
  }
}

async function confirmCode() {
  setLoading(true);

  try {
    await confirm.confirm(code);
    setConfirm(null);
    await AsyncStorage.setItem('@DidSignUp', 'true');
    await AsyncStorage.setItem(
      '@credentials',
      `{"name":"${name}","email":"${email}","phonenumber":"${
        '+98 ' + phonenumber
      }"}`
    );

    firestore().collection('users').doc(auth().currentUser.uid).set({
      name,
      email,
      phonenumber,
    });
  } catch (error) {
    setLoading(false);

    if (error.code !== 'auth/unknown') {
      alert('Invalid code !');
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On Android the Firebase Authentication SDK actually works with the OS to automatically detect the SMS containing the OTP. This is known as auto-retrieval and is [documented](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/android/phone-auth#verification-callbacks) as:

> Auto-retrieval: on some devices, Google Play services can automatically detect the incoming verification SMS and perform verification without user action. (This capability might be unavailable with some carriers.) This uses the [SMS Retriever API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever), which includes an 11 character hash at the end of the SMS message.

So this is a feature, and not a bug. :)
There seems to be no way to disable the feature, from what I can quickly tell: [How to disable Firebase Phone Auth Android auto-sign-in (onVerificationCompleted callback)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45356169/how-to-disable-firebase-phone-auth-android-auto-sign-in-onverificationcompleted)