# Login Authentication with phone number using firebase

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-authentication

Even if the OTP is correct, it is showing this error when enter the verification  code

> The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again

- I tried to delete Phone Number in test account
- I tried delete SHA-1 key or SHA-256 key and again re-enter on firebse console
- I tried json file replesh by new file

or when I try to login second time, I am not getting any code sms for the same number in same device.

how to resend OTP on request from the number and ?

Comment: could you please send your code ??

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44688761/how-to-resend-sms-verification-in-firebase-phone-authentication-android

Comment: @ahuja007 First problem is this The SMS code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again

Comment: it will be more helpful if we could see you Activity , the code that you have written

Comment: Check the following question. I think it is the same problem.  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57054891/the-sms-code-has-expired-please-re-send-the-verification-code-to-try-again